# FirebirdDB Cant Run Procedure While Its Backup Db Can

Tags: math, stored-procedures, overflow, truncation, firebird1.5

I had a trouble in my database here, I use Firebird 1.5.3 and it work just fine until noe to read or write in normal way, but when I run a procedure, I got blank row result and the following message :

> Arithmetic exception, numeric
>   overflow, or string truncation.
>
> SQL Code: -802 IB Error Number:
>   335544321

So I compared it with my backup db a month ago, it worked just fine, I get data in rows. To ensure my code wasnt change, I copy paste both procedure in WinMerge (diff comparer) but nothing diffrent. To ensure my error came from data, I run my procedure for old dated transaction (1 year old data), still I get those message.

I check the aritmethic logic in procedure, modifying, but no luck.
Did anyone can help with this?

Thx a bunch,

Comment: I think you should edit the title as the procedure runs and creates error.

Comment: Can you give us the procedure code? Maybe your procedure does a simple division by zero somewhere (and your old data did not have any zeroes :)

Comment: @ypercube Sorry I dont know how to edit the title.. and Im sorry I cant show you the code, its somewhat contain a crucial information of my company. But to assure you, yes I found a zero division, and I made a correction but still no change, and the other thing is, the old data (2008) in **backup db** can be processed by the procedure, while the same old data (2008) with the same month and the same data cant be processed by **live db**. I checked both code and data, its the same.. Doest anybody know how to check db setting of Firebird db 1.5.3? Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a long tracing into the code and data, I found the obstacle which somehow bugging me out. There was a change in a master data which now has longger character (varchar). In my procedure it was put into a smaller size of varchar, let say 10 character. While new string its about 15. Here goes the error **...or string truncation....**. But anyway thanks of your attention to my problem and thanks for the clues you wrote, it save me somehow, give me the idea to trace it up.

Thx a bunch,

Answer (score 0):

Different behaviour (in backup db and live one) with exactly same data is strange. Perhaps some other procedure or trigger is messing up with your query in the live db.

Since you say that you can't publish the code here, I'll suggest something you can try to eliminate some other possibilities.

*"numeric overflow, or string truncation."* is the error you get.

- Does the query have `SUM()` or other
  aggegate function?
- Does it have any string manipulating function?

If yes on any of the above, try to remove any such part, one by one, and run the modified query. So you may spot which part of the query produces the error.

---

Note: Same db structure, same data and same query do **not** always produce same results because of non-deterministic functions like `NOW()` and `RAND()`. If the results of these functions are used in further computations, then arithmetic errors like division by 0 or overflow or other types of errors can occur in one run and not in another.